# Keep JavaFX TreeTableView sorted when Items change

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFX application with a `TreeTableView` that shows a tree of items that can change in two ways:

1. Items may be added or removed in the background
2. The data of the items (shown in the table columns) may change

The TreeTableView, like the TableView, can be sorted either by users clickinig on the column headers or by setting the sort order in the code. This sorting however does not seem to persist when new items are added or when the data changes.

Here is a simple example (tested with OpenJFX 20) that shows my problem. A table is created and also a button for adding random tree elements. Even though the table is supposed to be sorted by the first column, new items always show up on the last row instead of being inserted at their correct location. Only manually re-sorting restores the correct order.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Random;

public class TestApplication extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TreeTableColumn<Entry, String> columnFirst = new TreeTableColumn<>("First");
        columnFirst.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().getValue().firstProperty());

        TreeTableColumn<Entry, String> columnSecond = new TreeTableColumn<>("Second");
        columnSecond.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().getValue().secondProperty());

        TreeTableView<Entry> treeTableView = new TreeTableView<>();
        treeTableView.getColumns().add(columnFirst);
        treeTableView.getColumns().add(columnSecond);

        Button button = new Button("Add Entry");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            Random random = new Random();
            String first = String.valueOf((char)(random.nextInt('Z' - 'A') + 'A'));
            String second = String.valueOf((char)(random.nextInt('Z' - 'A') + 'A'));
            Entry entry = new Entry(first, second);

            if(treeTableView.getRoot() == null) {
                treeTableView.setRoot(new TreeItem<>(entry));
                treeTableView.getRoot().setExpanded(true);
                treeTableView.getSortOrder().add(columnFirst);
            }
            else {
                treeTableView.getRoot().getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(entry));
            }
        });

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().add(treeTableView);
        vbox.getChildren().add(button);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("TreeTableView Sorting");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class Entry {
        private final String first;
        private final String second;

        public Entry(String first, String second) {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
        }

        public ReadOnlyStringProperty firstProperty() {
            return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(first);
        }

        public ReadOnlyStringProperty secondProperty() {
            return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(second);
        }
    }
}
```

For JavaFX's TableView I could achieve a persistent sorting by using a `SortedList<T>` and binding its comparator to that of the TableView (as suggested in the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html)).
Together with setting an [extractor](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.base/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList(javafx.util.Callback)) to observe changes to the list items themselves this basically solves the problem for the TableView. It just stays sorted in the user-specified way no matter how the data changes.

But I failed to find anything similar for the TreeTableView. The items have an internal observable list that can be accessed with `getChildren()` but there don't seem to be any customization points here.

Is there an obvious solution to this that I overlooked? Ideally I would like to avoid calling `sort()` after each change to the backing data.

Answer (score 0):

My best solution so far is to extend the `TreeItem` class and keep a separate, sorted list of children that is then mirrored to the actual list of children.
It is based on this Stackoverflow answer for filterable tree items: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34426897.

```
public class SortedTreeItem<T> extends TreeItem<T> {
    private final ObservableList<TreeItem<T>> sourceChildren;
    private final SortedList<TreeItem<T>> sortedChildren;

    public SortedTreeItem(T value, Callback<T, Observable[]> extractor) {
        super(value, null);

        // Initialize source list with given extractor
        sourceChildren = FXCollections.observableArrayList(item -> extractor.call(item.getValue()));

        // Create sorted list of children backed by the source list
        sortedChildren = new SortedList<>(sourceChildren);

        // Keep actual children list in sync with the sorted children
        // We can't just override getChildren() because of https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8089158
        Bindings.bindContent(getChildren(), sortedChildren);
    }

    // Comparator by which the child items are sorted
    public ObjectProperty<Comparator<? super TreeItem<T>>> comparatorProperty() {
        return sortedChildren.comparatorProperty();
    }

    // For accessing and modifying the source list
    public ObservableList<TreeItem<T>> getSourceChildren() {
        return sourceChildren;
    }
}
```

One drawback is that the items must only be modified by using `getSourceChildren()`.
To enable sorting, the item's comparators are bound to that of the TreeTableView like this

```
SortedTreeItem<Entry> item = new SortedTreeItem<>(entry, Entry::extractor);
item.comparatorProperty().bind(treeTableView.comparatorProperty());
```

Also, the default sorting (which would interfere with this solution) is disabled by giving the table an empty sort policy

```
treeTableView.setSortPolicy(table -> true);
```